# How to assign one dimensional array values to two dimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I am quite new in Matlab, and I want to assign the value of 1D array to 2D array, and I searched most of the books but I didn't get what I want to know.help me out guys.The code is like

```
while (count1~=17)

      while (count2~=257)

          A[count1][count2]= fc1[count2];
          count2=count2+1;
      end   
      count1=count1+1;

end
```

And the error is saying in the line A[count1][count2]= fc1[count2];

Comment: What is the error?
Please write here!

Comment: If the posted code is literal, then I would wager it's because that's not how you [index matrices in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Comment: Have a look at `reshape`. It does what you want. Also, check out Language Fundamentals as suggested in the answer you got.

Answer (score 0):

First of a all you are using the wrong syntax for assigning matrices in MATALB. You should start reading the documentation for getting firm with the language fundamentals:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html

You will see that the assignment of `A` has to look as follows:

`A(count1,count2)= fc1(count2)`

Furthermore you should have a look at the initialization of your variables. In the code above, the inner loop will only run once, until you don't reset `count2`